# Trigger macro at text+F9

Tags: vba, ms-word

I would like to run a certain macro if a certain text has been typed and if F9 was pressed afterwards, for example:

```
The patient has been diagnosed with DIA1
```

, followed by the F9 key.

Word should react on the F9 key and run the macro DIA1 which would erase the word "DIA1" from the typed text and insert a certain text.

How could I do this?

Comment: Do you mean when F9 is pressed, it should look for the last word typed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Two things:**

1- Solution finds "DIA1" within the last line, it doesn't check the last word. If you insist on the last word here it is:

```
Sub Lastword()
    Dim rng As Range, wrd As String
    Set rng = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Last.Range
    wrd = StrReverse(Trim(Left(StrReverse(rng), InStr(1, StrReverse(rng), " ", vbTextCompare))))
    MsgBox wrd
End Sub
```

2- F9-F12 are reserved so your closest option is F8. Alternatively you can assign macro to F9 by following [these steps](https://wordribbon.tips.net/T008058_Assigning_a_Macro_to_a_Shortcut_Key.html), as @Ibo suggested.

**Solution:**

1-Bind F8 to your macro

```
Sub Bind()
    Application.CustomizationContext = ThisDocument.AttachedTemplate
    KeyBindings.Add KeyCode:=BuildKeyCode(wdKeyF8), KeyCategory:=wdKeyCategoryMacro, Command:="Runme"
End Sub
```

2- "Find and replace" macro:

```
Sub Runme()
    Dim rng  As Range
    Set rng = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Last.Range
    rng.Find.Execute FindText:="DIA1", ReplaceWith:="hello", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

3-If you need to unbind F8:

```
Sub Unbind()
    CustomizationContext = NormalTemplate
    FindKey(BuildKeyCode(wdKeyF8)).Clear
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to define the macro that will trigger on F9 and then assign F9 to it. [Learn How](https://wordribbon.tips.net/T008058_Assigning_a_Macro_to_a_Shortcut_Key.html)

Let's say the name of this macro will be ttt. I assume that when you press F9, you just typed the function name to run. Let's say DIA1. This is the structure you should follow. You need to add lines you need to replace the string DIA1 etc though, but this works. I tested myself

```
Sub DIA1()
    MsgBox "hello"
End Sub


Sub ttt()
    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.Copy

    Application.Run CStr(Selection)
End Sub
```